# Автовосстановление веб-приложение после критической ошибки внутри докера

Tags: c#, docker

Есть веб-приложение, крутится оно в линуксовом докере.
Допускается вероятность, что когда-то оно почему-то упадёт (какой-то крит по любой причине), как заставить его перезапускаться автоматически сразу после падения?

Мне на ум приходит только какой-то "Launcher", который будет внутри себя контролировать жизненный цикл приложухи (ловить необработанные ошибки и запускать новый инстанс в крайнем случае).

Мб есть какие-то более корректные/правильные решения?

Comment: Гугл посоветовал эту ссылку https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/start-containers-automatically/

Comment: А разве контейнер обязательно упадёт вместе с приложением внутри него?

Comment: Зависит от того, как вы настроите запуск. Если ваше приложение прописано в команде запуска контейнера, то контейнер завершится вместе с приложением.

Comment: @PakUula Звучит как решение. Спасибо!